# Change background image of eBay listing, shows up in IE, but not Chrome/Firefox/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I tried to change the default eBay background image, but none works.

Here is eBay's CSS:

```css
html body{background:url(http://www.xx.com/AAA.jpg); }
```

I added a new CSS file that contains:

```css
html body{background:url(http://www.xx.com/BBB.jpg); }
```

After loading, the AAA image eBay sets shows up, and I opened inspected element from Chrome, the computed CSS shows only:

```css
body{background:url(http://www.xx.com/AAA.jpg); }
```

Normally, when setting the same element with different CSS a couple times, the browser will shows:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://www.xx.com/AAA.jpg);
}

body {
  background: url(http://www.xx.com/BBB.jpg);
}

body {
  background: url(http://www.xx.com/CCC.jpg);
}

body {
  background: url(http://www.xx.com/DDD.jpg);
}
```

So I know the CSS is being loaded, but got overrides by a later version. But eBay seems not loading any CSS that has the same element name or id or class. Can any one tell me how to change the background image in eBay auction listings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you search for "!important" - append this to your background CSS-statement to tell the browser to make it the first choice and ignore other definitions.

```
body {
       background:url(http://www.xx.com/BBB.jpg) !important; 
}
```